# How can I use DOT files to export data's?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to export data into a word doc using ".dot" models, with an application written in asp.net.
Can you give me some links to learn this trick? I'm sure is it possible without any external libraries.
Thanks to the universal knowledge ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you will able to do this without any extra libraries.

If you are using Word 2007+ format (eg .docx, .dotx) you can use the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en).  If not, your best bet is probably [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have MS Word installed on the machine that will fill the templates (.dot files), and then you can call an instance of Word to do the replacements for you, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

If this has to be implemented on a server, you might have a problem. Microsoft advises against installing Office on servers because of stability and reliability issues. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 focusses on some of these problems and also mentions some alternatives.